# Pattern matching analysis with CSV file and store the result in an arrays

Tags: text-processing, csv

The codec files to be played to the users are `CODEC=welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u`.

From the log, codec files played to the users are grep and stored in the `E41.csv` file.

Content of that CSV file for the users where two codecs were played correctly:

```
users,codec1,codec2
9188888881,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9177777772,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9166666663,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9155555554,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9144444445,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
```

csv file content can be for 1 user out of 5, both the codecs were not played, user disconnected the call immediately: [note the user 9177777772]

```
users,codec1,codec2
9188888881,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9177777772,
9166666663,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9155555554,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9144444445,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
```

Similarly, there can be a user who disconnected once `welcome1` alone played and similarly `Announcement` too.

```
9188888881,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9177777772,welcome1.g711u
9166666663,,Announcementbui4.g711u
9155555554,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9144444445,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
```

---

1. I want [users] to whom the codecs played fully to be store in an array `-(fully_played[]).`
2. User who were not played any codecs to be stored in an array `-(not_played[]).`
3. Only welcome codec played to the users to be stored in an array `-(codec1_played[])`
4. Only Announcement codec played to the users to be stored in an array `-(codec2_played[]).`

What I tried so far:

```
codec12="$( awk -F, '{if (($2 == "welcome1.g711u") && ($3 == "Announcementbui4.g711u")) { print $1 } }' $CURRENTPATH/E41.csv | head)"
{ printf "%s\n" "$codec12"; }>$CURRENTPATH/codec12.csv

name=( $(awk '{print $1}' $CURRENTPATH/codec12.csv) )
echo ${name[*]}
len4=${#name[*]}
echo $len4
```

returns 4

Instead of redirecting into .csv file and again storing into an array looks tedious. Is there any way to store the awk pattern matching into an array?

Comment: When I tried to convert the variable codec12 into an array, like $codec12{[@]}, it prints as one record like 9188888881 9166666663 9155555554 9144444445. The length of codec12 array appears to be 1, instead of 4.

Comment: Note: I am discussing the scenario, where welcome1.g711u & Annoucementbiu4.g711u were played successfully for 4/5 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to store the user IDs in bash arrays, it seems unlikely you can avoid multiple calls of `awk`. The following bash script should do the task:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

fully_played=( $(awk -F, 'FNR>1 && $2 && $3 {print $1}' "$1") )
not_played=( $(awk -F, 'FNR>1 && !$2 && !$3 {print $1}' "$1") )
codec1_played=( $(awk -F, 'FNR>1 && $2 && !$3 {print $1}' "$1") )
codec2_played=( $(awk -F, 'FNR>1 && !$2 && $3 {print $1}' "$1") )

echo "Fully played: ${#fully_played[@]} - ${fully_played[@]}"
echo "Not played: ${#not_played[@]} - ${not_played[@]}"
echo "Codec1 played: ${#codec1_played[@]} - ${codec1_played[@]}"
echo "Codec2 played: ${#codec2_played[@]} - ${codec2_played[@]}"
```

You would supply the CSV file as first argument to the shell script (`$1`).

The four `awk` calls would then

- store the user names (first column value) of all lines (disregarding the first line, which contain the column titles) where both the second and third column are non-empty in the array `fully_played`
- store the user names of all lines where both the second and third column are empty in the array `not_played`
- store the user names of all lines where the second column is non-empty, but the third column is empty, in the array `codec1_played`
- store the user names of all lines where the second column is empty, but the third column is non-empty, in the array `codec2_played`

All lines after the `awk` calls only serve to demonstrate that the arrays are correctly filled.